# Sql create table check date

Tags: sql, date

On creating table i needed to add a check statement for current date should be created date cell. So for example

```
create table own_departments
(
id number(4) primary key,
name varchar2(30),
num_of_emps number(4) default '0',
est_date date,
check(est_date < sysdate)
);
```

This check gives errors.

Is anyone know how to check DATE format???

Comment: What version of SQL are you using? MSSQL, MYSQL, ORACLE?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server then you will need to create a table constraint...

```
ALTER TABLE _departments WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT CK_DateGreaterThan CHECK  (([est_date]>YOUR_DATE))
GO

ALTER TABLE _departments CHECK CONSTRAINT CK_DateGreaterThan 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server / Oracle / MS Access, then it should be something like this:

```
create table own_departments
(
id number(4) primary key,
name varchar2(30),
num_of_emps number(4) default '0',
**est_date date check(est_date < sysdate)**
);
```

Comment: I AM USING ORACLE SQLDEVELOPER.

Comment: @ Serbay Agûn. Has my answer worked for you? the syntax between ** and **. Try it and let us know